# Silex - How to pass / retrieve a parameter from the header

Tags: request, silex, guzzle

I currently got a FE / BE setup. I managed to get the FE to retrieve data from the BE but I am in the progress of trying to pass a token via the header which I seem to be completely oblivious to how to get this done. I am using guzzle to handle my request to external source.

here is my FE call:

```
$client = new Client([
        // Base URI is used with relative requests
        'base_uri' => $app['fomservices']['sis'],
    ]);

    $response = $client->request('GET', 'admitted', ['Authorization' => $token]);
```

Once on the back end, I can't seem to figure out how to even access the header of my $request. There isn't anything in the auto complete that hints me toward this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Request class has a member called `headers` of type `HeaderBag`.  `HeaderBag` is a simple interface for managing headers.

```
$request->headers->get("Authorization")
```